# Can the strong force be explained by quaternions?

Tags: group-theory, complex-numbers, yang-mills, strong-force

I wonder if the strong force can be explained by [quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) without the use of matrices.

I heard that it could, but the source was not reliable.

Comment: Probably they are relating something like pion model (isospin model to strong force), which has an algebraic strucuture equal to unit quaternions, but not the SU(3) QCD algebra.

Comment: Quaternions can be represented by matrices, so that would be mathematically equivalent, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Your source probably misunderstood.

In [Gauge Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_theory), the U(1) group describes [electromagnetism](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/258263/why-is-u1-the-gauge-group-in-classical-electromagnetism), SU(2) describes [weak interaction](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/192842/role-of-su2-group-in-isospin-and-in-the-weak-interaction), and SU(3) describes [strong interaction](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/108641/why-is-su3-chosen-as-the-gauge-group-in-qcd).

Mathematically, U(1) is isomorphic to the unitary complex numbers (or the unit circle), SU(2) to unit quaternions (or the [unit 3-sphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189956/what-does-su2-is-homeomorphic-to-the-unit-3-sphere-in-r4-mean)), and SU(3) to a [more complicated thing](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/69352/topology-of-su3).

Furthermore, as CuriousOne comments, elements of an *n*-dimensional field can be represented as *n*x1 matrices (*n*=4 for quaternion). **The weak force can be explained with quaternions** instead of matrices, but underneath it's really just the same math in different clothing.

Describing the strong force requires at least 8 independent terms, but quaternions only have 4. Maybe your source meant [octonions](https://www.quantamagazine.org/the-octonion-math-that-could-underpin-physics-20180720/).